# IOS push notifications in foreground Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, foreground

I am working on IOS application where I am working on Push Notifications by using Parse SDK. I am able to get the notifications when my back is in background. Now I want to receive Notifications even if my App is in foreground. I have searched many code for it but it didn't suites in my current AppDelegate class.

How to get Push Notifications even if my app is in foreground?

```
 @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = "asdasdasd"
            $0.clientKey = "asdasdasdas"
            $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
        }
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }

        return true
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData: deviceToken)
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }
    }
}
```

I have found this solution from same forum but I am not able to put the following code snippet in my current Code:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo


        // Print full message.
        print("tap on on forground app",userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: Unable means I am confused where and how to put the above code snippet which I wrote which I found from same forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since iOS 10, apple allow users to handle Push Notification presentation while in foreground. you can handle that in `willPresent` method. and handle the Push Notification in the completionHandler, pass your desired options i.e. alert, badge and sound.

Confirm you appDelegate to use  `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

put this in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Before

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
```

And add this method

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

**iOS 14 Update**
.alert has been depreciated, you should now use .banner, like so:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
       {
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
       }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Where exactly I have to put this function? Do I need to call it explicitly with function name?

Comment: just put this function in appdelegate. you dont need to call it, it will be called automatically

Comment: conferm you appdelegate to use UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Comment: Still it's not working. I have updated my code in my question. Please check it and guide me what I am doing wrong there.

Comment: @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

Comment: add this instead of your class implementation

Comment: Thanks Ajay saini.. It is working now.. Just one small help, my Push Sound is not coming when I am receiving any push

Comment: Please make sure you are sending "sound":"default" key in your notification. or check for you ring silent button in your device

Comment: I am doing both right now.. Voice button is ON and sound is also going. But still not getting a voice